# How to detect a event searching between 2 datetimes columns

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list events saved on DB. I want to detect using querys if the event can be saved or not.

There is a form with 3 fields:

- Item
- StartDate
- EndDate

When the user click on save. The system must check if the event is available in the time range.

Here are a example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/88b27/1

If for example i want to reserve a event from start 'September, 09 2013 15:00:00' and ends on 'September, 09 2013 17:00:00' (2hours duration). This cant be done because exist a prev event (id=18) that have start time September, 09 2013 14:00:00. But i dont know how make the query. I have a query using between but without success.

Answer (score 1):

The following query tells you if there are any existing reservations that affect the period:

```
SELECT  *
FROM reservaciones
WHERE FechaEnd >= '2013-09-09 14:00:00' AND
      FechaStart <= '2013-09-09 18:00:00';
```

Note:  the `<=` and `>=` might really be `<` and `>` depending on whether the end points are inclusive or not.

The reasoning is simple.  Two periods overlap when one starts before the other ends and also ends after the other starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily accomplish this by asking the DB if there are any events between those two dates. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM EVENTS WHERE EVENT_DATE BETWEEN STARTDATE AND ENDDATE
```

If the query returns results, you know that you can  not accept the new event.

This is ambiguous because you don't specify what database fields you have, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  * FROM reservaciones 
WHERE '2013-09-09 20:00:10' BETWEEN FechaStart AND FechaEnd 
OR '2013-09-09 21:00:00' BETWEEN FechaStart And FechaEnd
```

If there is a row, then it means it is not possible to reserve from that time

**Explanation**

There are two cases to determine whether the submitted event is overlapped with another event.

- The first case is when started datetime of the submitted event is overlapped with another event.

  ```
   ^********************^  <-- another event
              ^*********************^  <-- current event
  ```
- The second case is when ended datetime of the submitted event is overlapped with another event

  ```
                ^********************^  <-- another event
      ^*********************^  <-- current event
  ```

As you can see from above figure that those two events are overlapped each other. The event that is not overlap with each other will look like this

```
  ^********************^  <-- another event
                          ^*********************^  <-- current event
```